# Angular 2 Component communication confusion

Tags: angular

i have recently started using angular 2 for a new project and haven some confusion on whats the best approach for the following.

I have a parent component (ROOT) which has 3 child components, A(a list of search result items in a table format), B(a google map) and C(a form with multiple inputs/select dropdowns ).

Component C (the refine form) should be the main driver in terms of the search criteria params used by an API endpoint located in a service i have injected into the ROOT parent component. The object returned (currently an observable from the http call) will be used to feed all 3 child components, render the list, map etc.

Now, what i really cant get my head around is:

1) How should i get the data out of the inputs/selects in the refine search component? Should i implement ouputs for each of the fields? or should the root parent used viewChild to somehow listen to changes to them?

2) Should i subscribe to the service observable in the parent, and then pass it to the list and map components?

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated, theres a hell of a lot to learn im still trying to get my head around it all and not sure if im even approaching it in the right way :/

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use to designing collections of components like this is to have an informal notion of a *smart* and a *dumb* component and decide whether each component should be, based on the following criteria.

1. A dumb component knows nothing of the world around it, if it has injected dependencies they are all stateless and synchronous. A dumb component never uses async except to pass DOM events to one of it's outputs.
2. A smart component is aware of the world around it. It can have access stateful services and is responsible for the inputs and outputs of it's dumb children. *Except for positioning dumb children within a container*, a smart component should not be concerned with display or user input.

This then gives a neat way of defining how components communicate.

- Two dumb components should **never** communicate with each other, **unless** one is a direct ancestor of the other. It should treat all children as if they were dumb components.
- A smart component interacts with dumb children via their `@Input`s and their `@Output`s.
- Two smart components communicate with each other (and the outside world) via injected services.

Based on your description of components 'A, B and C', here's how I'd categorise them

## A: A list of search results.

Definitely a dumb component. It should have an `@Input()` for accepting the list of results, but the component has nothing to do with actually searching for the results, it just displays them.

## B: A google map

Another dumb component, it just takes as `@Input` the options to display on the map and displays the map. It can have `@Output`s based on user interaction with the map, but it is only concerned with displaying the data.

## C: The form

Yep, you guessed right, another dumb component. It has an input which is the current model, and an output for when the user clicks the save button. It doesn't need to know about what the user has input, it just needs to provide the capability to enter the input (and validation for when the input is incorrect).

## D: The root component

The smart component, in this simple example. It is not concerned with displaying the data, or accepting user input, it is responsible for coordinating interaction between the list, input and the map.

It should take data from the form, manipulate the api and display the results in the result container, making liberal use of the `AsyncPipe` from `@angular/common` so that none of the results, map or form have to know anything about each other.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain, that makes sense! in terms of getting the data from the form, we wanted the api data to refresh whenever the form fields were changed (i.e not on a submit click as such). Would it be a case of passing a new observable object (with properties for the inputs to bind to) into the form component and subscribing to changes to it? or do i have that totally wrong?

Comment: Don't use async in forms, it just leads to pain and confusion

Have one input, `values` and two outputs on the form `valuesChange` and `commit` -- the root component would subscribe to `valuesChanges` when a form field has changed (with potentially invalid data), and `commit` when the form is saved.

In the root component, handle the data via the api service and then pass back the result into `values` to redraw the form. You could also use `Observable.debounce` on the `changed` event emitter to avoid spamming your server with requests.

Comment: ps. another alternative is to pass in an async validation function from the root component via an `@Input` and use it when constructing the `control` in the form (if you're using reactive forms, which you should be ;)).

Comment: Ok, so silly question, would a need to have a changes @output event emitter for each input field in the form component and handle the changes event for each on in the root? or? sorry mate, really appreciate your time

Comment: It's OK, I've been through this pain myself.

Define a model object which contains all the data that you want in the form, map and results. Pass that into the `values` input, let the user manipulate it and then pass it back to the root via the `valuesChange` output.

Comment: Most of the time, if I can't think of a good name for a class that I can pass into and out of a form in one discrete unit, then is a clear indicator that I need to split my form up into multiple forms.

Comment: Yeh, i think in this situation it felt right to move the "advanced search" form into its own component as it may well be used in other sections of the app. The most confusion comes from knowing in the root component (where the actual api service is injected) when any of the form values had changed so that the api "getSearch" method can be called again. I take it that id just handle the call to get results again in the valueChange function in the root? and now we're in the realms of rxjs and subscriptions right? its all such a steep learning curve mate!

Comment: Since you're having a bit of trouble getting your head around things, I've written up [a quick gist](https://gist.github.com/ovangle/413a7b26e32ca6935a8d079111fd843c) which is a map which gets the current state from some service that stores the current map options, and a prefilling service that takes the zoom and position from a form and adds some other fields to the object passed to the map.

I don't guarantee it works (or is even syntactially valid), but it should give you an idea of how to connect up your comonents

Comment: Thanks so much! Ill take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use `Input` to pass data to child component upto first level `[first level child only]` and `Output` to emit event to imediate parent not for parent of parent.

There are different ways with which you can interact with your components. You can find all at [component communication guide.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#table-of-contents) But i will suggest you to go with the [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) so that you do not need to define more inputs and output on component.

You can check https://gist.github.com/ranakrunal9/7b26ccafbe29fcf4bdac4f9236e71e6a[3](https://gist.github.com/ranakrunal9/7b26ccafbe29fcf4bdac4f9236e71e6a) for Parent and children communicate via a service.